# identify the columns have specific value for each row in python

Tags: python

I'm newer at python.
I have a dataframe like this

```
            1   2   3   
 75016      1   2   2   
 75017      0   0   0       
 75018      0   2   2
```

For each row, I want to identify what the columns have the value = 1 or 2
the output =

```
" 75016 " has = column 1,2,3
" 75017 " has column
" 75018 " has column 2,3
```

how I can do it?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) DataFrame, you can use:

```
s = df.stack().isin([1,2])
out = (s[s]
       .reset_index(1)
       .groupby(level=0)['level_1']
       .agg(','.join)
       .reindex(df.index).fillna('')
      )
```

output:

```
75016    1,2,3
75017         
75018      2,3
Name: level_1, dtype: object
```

used input:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'1': [1, 0, 0], '2': [2, 0, 2], '3': [2, 0, 2]},
                  index=[75016, 75017, 75018])
```

Comment: I try the code, this the output that appear : 75016     
75017     
75018     
Name: level_1, dtype: object

Comment: please provide the output of `df.to_dict()` (as [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72345306/edit) to your question)

Comment: {'1': {75016: '1',
  75017: '0',
  75018: '0' } and so on ... the difference in creating a dataframe, I read from csv to dataframe .. how can I solve problem now?

Comment: can you provide the full output? If your values are **strings**, use `.isin(['1','2'])` in place of `.isin([1,2])`